# differences between INSERT select and insert into select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I often see two styles, INSERT select and insert into select, what are the differences? Are they the same?

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.

Here are two samples.

```
INSERT california_authors (au_id, au_lname, au_fname)
SELECT au_id, au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors
WHERE State = 'CA'
```

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-select-to-insert-records

```
INSERT INTO Store_Information (store_name, Sales, Date)
SELECT store_name, Sales, Date
FROM Sales_Information
```

http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In `SQL Server` and `MySQL`,  `INTO` is pure syntax sugar.

No difference.

`Oracle` and `PostgreSQL` require this keyword to be present, and, `AFAIR`, `ANSI` `SQL` standards do too.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: what's the difference between a query and a statement?

Comment: Sorry my knowledge wasn't correct till yesterday. Actually query will return some data while statement won't.

Answer (score 6):

They're the same; the `INTO` is just optional.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the two statements you have listed are in fact the same. The "INTO" statement is missing in the first batch but it is implied as part of the INSERT statement.

For illustration purposes, here are some different forms of using the INSERT statement.

```
SELECT 
    1 AS ID ,
    'SomeText' AS SomeText
INTO #tmpTableName

INSERT INTO #tmpTableName (ID,SomeText) 
SELECT 2, 'Text' 

INSERT INTO #tmpTableName (ID,SomeText) 
VALUES(3, 'MoreText')

SELECT * FROM #tmpTableName

DROP TABLE #tmpTableName
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT...INTO` creates a new table, while `INSERT...SELECT` requires an existing table.  So there are security implications and possible performance issues to consider.

Also, with `SELECT...INTO`, the new table has the same columns but no keys or constraints, so it is best for simply creating a temp backup.

Comment: I don't think he's asking about SELECT...INTO.  He's asking about INSERT SELECT and INSERT INTO SELECT